# Por qué no reconoce el imageview

Tags: mysql, android-studio

```
package x.huertalia;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import  java.lang.NullPointerException;
import android.util.Base64;
import java.lang.Object.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.widget.ImageView.*;
import static x.huertalia.R.*;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button consultar;
    Button consultarporid;
    Button insertar;
    Button actualizar;
    Button borrar;
    EditText idendificador;
    EditText nombre;
    EditText direccion;
    EditText telefono;
    EditText producto;
    EditText precio;
    TextView resultado;
    // ImageView imageView;

    // IP de mi Url
    String IP = "http://yoelabreu8a.esy.es";
    // Rutas de los Web Services
    String GET = IP + "/obtener_alumnos.php";
    String GET_BY_ID = IP + "/obtener_alumno_por_id.php";
    String UPDATE = IP + "/actualizar_alumno.php";
    String DELETE = IP + "/borrar_alumno.php";
    String INSERT = IP + "/insertar_alumno.php";

    ObtenerWebService hiloconexion;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( layout.activity_main );
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById ( id.toolbar );
        setSupportActionBar ( toolbar );


        // Enlaces con elementos visuales del XML

        consultar = (Button) findViewById ( id.consultar );
        consultarporid = (Button) findViewById ( id.consultarid );
        insertar = (Button) findViewById ( id.insertar );
        actualizar = (Button) findViewById ( id.actualizar );
        borrar = (Button) findViewById ( id.borrar );
        idendificador = (EditText) findViewById ( id.eid );
        nombre = (EditText) findViewById ( id.enombre );
        direccion = (EditText) findViewById ( id.edireccion );
        telefono = (EditText) findViewById ( id.etelefono );
        producto = (EditText) findViewById ( id.eproducto );
        precio = (EditText) findViewById ( id.eprecio );
        resultado = (TextView) findViewById ( id.resultado );
        //   imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        // Listener de los botones

        consultar.setOnClickListener ( this );
        consultarporid.setOnClickListener ( this );
        insertar.setOnClickListener ( this );
        actualizar.setOnClickListener ( this );
        borrar.setOnClickListener ( this );


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById ( id.fab );
        fab.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make ( view, "info@huertalia.com", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG )
                        .setAction ( "Action", null ).show ();
            }
        } );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater ().inflate ( R.menu.menu_main, menu );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId ();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected ( item );
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId ()) {
            case id.consultar:

                hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService ();
                hiloconexion.execute ( GET, "1" );   // Parámetros que recibe doInBackground

                break;
            case id.consultarid:

                hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService ();
                String cadenallamada = GET_BY_ID + "?idalumno=" + idendificador.getText ().toString ();

                hiloconexion.execute ( cadenallamada, "2" );   // Parámetros que recibe doInBackground


                break;
            case id.insertar:

                hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService ();
                hiloconexion.execute ( INSERT, "3", nombre.getText ().toString (), direccion.getText ().toString (), producto.getText ().toString () );   // Parámetros que recibe doInBackground


                break;
            case id.actualizar:

                hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService ();
                hiloconexion.execute ( UPDATE, "4", idendificador.getText ().toString (), nombre.getText ().toString (), direccion.getText ().toString (), producto.getText ().toString () );   // Parámetros que recibe doInBackground


                break;
            case id.borrar:

                hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService ();
                hiloconexion.execute ( DELETE, "5", idendificador.getText ().toString () );   // Parámetros que recibe doInBackground


                break;
            default:

                break;
        }
    }

    public class ObtenerWebService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        Bitmap bitmap;
        String IMAGENES = IP + "/img/";
     //   private ImageView imagenView;
     //ImageView imageView;



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String cadena = params[0];
            URL url = null; // Url de donde queremos obtener información
            String devuelve = "";


            if (params[1].equals ( "1" )) {    // Consulta de todos los alumnos

                try {
                    url = new URL ( cadena );

                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection (); //Abrir la conexión
                    connection.setRequestProperty ( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0" +
                            " (Linux; Android 1.5; es-ES) Ejemplo HTTP" );
                    //connection.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

                    int respuesta = connection.getResponseCode ();
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder ();

                    if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {


                        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream ( connection.getInputStream () );  // preparo la cadena de entrada

                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader ( in ) );  // la introduzco en un BufferedReader

                        // El siguiente proceso lo hago porque el JSONOBject necesita un String y tengo
                        // que tranformar el BufferedReader a String. Esto lo hago a traves de un
                        // StringBuilder.

                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null) {
                            result.append ( line );        // Paso toda la entrada al StringBuilder
                        }

                        //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                        JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject ( result.toString () );   //Creo un JSONObject a partir del StringBuilder pasado a cadena
                        //Accedemos al vector de resultados

                        String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString ( "estado" );   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON


                        if (resultJSON.equals ( "1" )) {      // hay alumnos a mostrar
                            JSONArray alumnosJSON = respuestaJSON.getJSONArray ( "alumnos" );   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON
                            for (int i = 0; i < alumnosJSON.length (); i++) {
                                devuelve = devuelve + alumnosJSON.getJSONObject ( i ).getString ( "idalumno" ) + " " +
                                        alumnosJSON.getJSONObject ( i ).getString ( "nombre" ) + " " +
                                        alumnosJSON.getJSONObject ( i ).getString ( "producto" ) + " " +
                                        alumnosJSON.getJSONObject ( i ).getString ( "precio" ) + " " +
                                        alumnosJSON.getJSONObject ( i ).getString ( "telefono" ) + " " +
                                        alumnosJSON.getJSONObject ( i ).getString ( "direccion" ) + "\n";

                            }

                        } else if (resultJSON.equals ( "2" )) {
                            devuelve = "No hay agricultores";
                        }


                    }


                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }

                return devuelve;


            } else if (params[1].equals ( "2" )) {    // consulta por id

                try {
                    url = new URL ( cadena );

                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection (); //Abrir la conexión
                    connection.setRequestProperty ( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0" +
                            " (Linux; Android 1.5; es-ES) Ejemplo HTTP" );
                    //connection.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

                    int respuesta = connection.getResponseCode ();
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder ();

                    if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {


                        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream ( connection.getInputStream () );  // preparo la cadena de entrada

                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader ( in ) );  // la introduzco en un BufferedReader

                        // El siguiente proceso lo hago porque el JSONOBject necesita un String y tengo
                        // que tranformar el BufferedReader a String. Esto lo hago a traves de un
                        // StringBuilder.

                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null) {
                            result.append ( line );        // Paso toda la entrada al StringBuilder
                        }

                        //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                        JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject ( result.toString () );   //Creo un JSONObject a partir del StringBuilder pasado a cadena
                        //Accedemos al vector de resultados

                        String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString ( "estado" );   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON

                        if (resultJSON.equals ( "1" )) {      // hay un alumno que mostrar
                            devuelve = devuelve + respuestaJSON.getJSONObject ( "alumno" ).getString ( "idAlumno" ) + " " +
                                    respuestaJSON.getJSONObject ( "alumno" ).getString ( "nombre" ) + " " +
                                    // respuestaJSON.getJSONObject("alumno").getString("producto")+" " +
                                    // respuestaJSON.getJSONObject("alumno").getString("precio")+" " +
                                    // respuestaJSON.getJSONObject("alumno").getString("telefono")+" " +
                                    respuestaJSON.getJSONObject ( "alumno" ).getString ( "direccion" );


                            if (respuestaJSON.getJSONObject ( "alumno" ).getString ( "rutaimagen" ).equals ( "noimagen" )) {
                                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource ( getResources (), drawable.icon_fallo );
                            } else {

                                URL urlimagen = new URL ( IMAGENES + respuestaJSON.getJSONObject ( "alumno" ).getString ( "rutaimagen" ) );
                                HttpURLConnection conimagen = (HttpURLConnection) urlimagen.openConnection ();
                                conimagen.connect ();
                                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream ( conimagen.getInputStream () );


                            }


                        } else if (resultJSON.equals ( "2" )) {
                            devuelve = "No hay agricultores";
                        }


                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }

                return devuelve;


            } else if (params[1].equals ( "3" )) {    // insert

                try {
                    HttpURLConnection urlConn;

                    DataOutputStream printout;
                    DataInputStream input;
                    url = new URL ( cadena );
                    urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection ();
                    urlConn.setDoInput ( true );
                    urlConn.setDoOutput ( true );
                    urlConn.setUseCaches ( false );
                    urlConn.setRequestProperty ( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
                    urlConn.setRequestProperty ( "Accept", "application/json" );
                    urlConn.connect ();
                    //Creo el Objeto JSON
                    JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject ();
                    jsonParam.put ( "nombre", params[2] );
                    jsonParam.put ( "direccion", params[3] );
                    // jsonParam.put("producto", params[4]);
                    // jsonParam.put("precio", params[5]);
                    // jsonParam.put("telefono", params[6]);
                    // Envio los parámetros post.
                    OutputStream os = urlConn.getOutputStream ();
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (
                            new OutputStreamWriter ( os, "UTF-8" ) );
                    writer.write ( jsonParam.toString () );
                    writer.flush ();
                    writer.close ();

                    int respuesta = urlConn.getResponseCode ();


                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder ();

                    if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                        String line;
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader ( urlConn.getInputStream () ) );
                        while ((line = br.readLine ()) != null) {
                            result.append ( line );
                            //response+=line;
                        }

                        //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                        JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject ( result.toString () );   //Creo un JSONObject a partir del StringBuilder pasado a cadena
                        //Accedemos al vector de resultados

                        String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString ( "estado" );   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON

                        if (resultJSON.equals ( "1" )) {      // hay un alumno que mostrar
                            devuelve = "Agricultor insertado correctamente";

                        } else if (resultJSON.equals ( "2" )) {
                            devuelve = "El agricultor no pudo insertarse";
                        }

                    }

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }

                return devuelve;


            } else if (params[1].equals ( "4" )) {    // update

                try {
                    HttpURLConnection urlConn;

                    DataOutputStream printout;
                    DataInputStream input;
                    url = new URL ( cadena );
                    urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection ();
                    urlConn.setDoInput ( true );
                    urlConn.setDoOutput ( true );
                    urlConn.setUseCaches ( false );
                    urlConn.setRequestProperty ( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
                    urlConn.setRequestProperty ( "Accept", "application/json" );
                    urlConn.connect ();
                    //Creo el Objeto JSON
                    JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject ();
                    jsonParam.put ( "idalumno", params[2] );
                    jsonParam.put ( "nombre", params[3] );
                    jsonParam.put ( "direccion", params[4] );
                   // jsonParam.put ( "producto", params[4] );
                    // Envio los parámetros post.
                    OutputStream os = urlConn.getOutputStream ();
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (
                            new OutputStreamWriter ( os, "UTF-8" ) );
                    writer.write ( jsonParam.toString () );
                    writer.flush ();
                    writer.close ();

                    int respuesta = urlConn.getResponseCode ();


                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder ();

                    if (respuesta== HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                        String line;
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader ( urlConn.getInputStream () ) );
                        while ((line = br.readLine ()) != null) {
                            result.append ( line );
                            //response+=line;
                        }

                        //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                        JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject ( result.toString () );   //Creo un JSONObject a partir del StringBuilder pasado a cadena
                        //Accedemos al vector de resultados

                        String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString ( "estado" );   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON

                        if (resultJSON.equals ( "1" )) {      // hay un alumno que mostrar
                            devuelve = "Agricultor actualizado correctamente";

                        } else if (resultJSON.equals ( "2" )) {
                            devuelve = "El agricultor no pudo actualizarse";
                        }

                    }

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }

                return devuelve;

            } else if (params[1].equals ( "5" )) {    // delete

                try {
                    HttpURLConnection urlConn;

                    DataOutputStream printout;
                    DataInputStream input;
                    url = new URL ( cadena );
                    urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection ();
                    urlConn.setDoInput ( true );
                    urlConn.setDoOutput ( true );
                    urlConn.setUseCaches ( false );
                    urlConn.setRequestProperty ( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
                    urlConn.setRequestProperty ( "Accept", "application/json" );
                    urlConn.connect ();
                    //Creo el Objeto JSON
                    JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject ();
                    jsonParam.put ( "idalumno", params[2] );
                    // Envio los parámetros post.
                    OutputStream os = urlConn.getOutputStream ();
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (
                            new OutputStreamWriter ( os, "UTF-8" ) );
                    writer.write ( jsonParam.toString () );
                    writer.flush ();
                    writer.close ();

                    int respuesta = urlConn.getResponseCode ();


                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder ();

                    if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                        String line;
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader ( urlConn.getInputStream () ) );
                        while ((line = br.readLine ()) != null) {
                            result.append ( line );
                            //response+=line;
                        }

                        //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                        JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject ( result.toString () );   //Creo un JSONObject a partir del StringBuilder pasado a cadena
                        //Accedemos al vector de resultados

                        String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString ( "estado" );   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON

                        if (resultJSON.equals ( "1" )) {      // hay un alumno que mostrar
                            devuelve = "Agricultor borrado correctamente";

                        } else if (resultJSON.equals ( "2" )) {
                            devuelve = "No hay agricultores";
                        }

                    }

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }

                return devuelve;

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(String s) {
            super.onCancelled ( s );
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            resultado.setText ( s );




         imageView.setImageBitmap ( bitmap );  //NO reconocido pese a estar en el hilo principal

            //super.onPostExecute(s);
        }

        @Override

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute ();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate ( values );
        }
    }

}
```

---

> 11-11 12:19:04.714 11244-11244/x.huertalia E/HW-JPEG-DEC:
>   HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   11-11 12:19:04.715 11244-11244/x.huertalia E/HW-JPEG-DEC:
>   HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   11-11 12:19:04.716 11244-11244/x.huertalia E/HW-JPEG-DEC:
>   HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   11-11 12:19:04.739 11244-11244/x.huertalia E/HW-JPEG-DEC:
>   HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   11-11 12:19:04.894 11244-11263/x.huertalia E/OpenGLRenderer: allen
>   debug liyu Key: 0 11-11 12:19:04.900 11244-11263/x.huertalia
>   E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 240518168576 11-11
>   12:19:04.901 11244-11263/x.huertalia E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug
>   liyu Key: 68724719680 11-11 12:19:04.903 11244-11263/x.huertalia
>   E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 34359738371 11-11 12:19:04.904
>   11244-11263/x.huertalia E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key:
>   5242945 11-11 12:19:04.905 11244-11263/x.huertalia E/OpenGLRenderer:
>   allen debug liyu Key: 5242944 11-11 12:19:04.908
>   11244-11263/x.huertalia E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key:
>   68719476744 11-11 12:19:04.909 11244-11263/x.huertalia
>   E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 1 11-11 12:19:05.142
>   11244-11263/x.huertalia E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key:
>   34364981312 11-11 12:19:06.643 11244-11263/x.huertalia
>   E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 103084458052 11-11
>   12:19:21.442 11244-11264/x.huertalia E/HW-JPEG-DEC:
>   HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null

Comment: Siguiendo los consejos que han compartido conmigo, he puesto el logcat. La pegunta es por que no reconoce el imageView.setImageBitmap ( bitmap ); en el postexecute. Muchisimas gracias

Comment: El logcat que has compartido no parece decir nada relevante de tu error, pero puede que `bitmap` sea nulo porque no estás obteniendo los recursos del contexto, tampoco estás usando la clase `R` para obtener la imagen. Deberías cambiar esta línea: `bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource ( getResources (), drawable.icon_fallo );` por: **`bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource (getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.icon_fallo );`** Aparte del problema, es curioso ver tu código escrito dando espacios siempre en los paréntesis `( ` y `)`... todo lo contrario de la práctica habitual en Java.

Comment: El problema es que imageView el postexecute no lo reconoce, igualmente he probado lo que me has dicho y no lo soluciona. Igualmente gracias

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error exacto que te da en el logcat? Lo que has compartido no describe nada del error. Y en cuanto a las peticiones remotas, recomendaría usar Volley, que es mucho más eficaz y menos complicado que AsyncTask. Pero eso es ya decisión tuya.

Comment: La librería volley era mi segunda opción

Comment: Si fuera tú me pasaría a Volley pero ya. Atención, **me refiero a la librería [Volley oficial de Android](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)**... en el pasado hubo una librería llamada del mismo modo que no funcionaba bien, pero con la Volley actual te vas a sorprender de la simplicidad que adquieren ese tipo de manejos que con `AsyncTask` resultan ser complicados. Volley maneja ella misma los hilos y esas cosas que a veces resultan oscuras para el programador. No te puedo ayudar más porque en realidad nunca he usando `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

No estas asignado la variable `imageView` que esta definida en la clase `ObtenerWebService`.

Intenta enviando la referencia del `imageView` en el constructor de la clase `ObtenerWebService`:

```
 public class ObtenerWebService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    String IMAGENES = IP + "/img/";
    private ImageView imagenView;
    //ImageView imageView;    
    public ObtenerWebService(ImageView imgView)
    {
        this.imageView = imgView;
    }
   //...
```

Entonces su uso ahora seria asi:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId ()) {
            case id.consultar:

                // le envias el imageView para que pueda actualizarlo en el metodo onPostExecuted(string)
                hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService (imageView);
                hiloconexion.execute ( GET, "1" );   // Parámetros que recibe doInBackground

                break;
              //...
```

Recuerda descomentar la variable imageView en la clase `MainActivity`.

Comment: Nada me tira la app abajo

Comment: Que error te lanza?

Comment: C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Huertalia\app\src\main\java\x\huertalia\MainActivity.java:160: error: constructor ObtenerWebService in class MainActivity.ObtenerWebService cannot be applied to given types;
                hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService ();

Comment: Siempre que inicializes la instancia de la clase ObtenerWebService() tienes que enviarle la referencia de la imagen.

Comment: public class ObtenerWebService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        String IMAGENES = IP + "/img/";
        private ImageView imagenView;
        ImageView imageView;
        public ObtenerWebService(ImageView imgView)
        {
            this.imageView = imgView;
        }

Comment: Como esta indicado en el ejemplo, siempre que hagas `new ObtenerWebService()` tienes que enviarle la referencia de la imagen `new ObtenerWebService(imageView);`

Comment: Luego en el swich me obliga a poner imageView en todos los casos

Comment: Si y asi debe de ser. Como siempre que ejecutas el servicio modificas el imageView, entonces es necesario enviarle la referencia del mismo siempre, no crees?

Comment: Si muchas gracias, pero lo curioso es comentando el imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); la aplicación funciona en cuanto descomento tira la app abajo.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que cuando ejecutas el metodo onPostExecute asumes que la variable bitmap nunca sera null. Deberias de verificar si no es null.